# How to improve fonts displayed in evince?

Tags: fonts, pdf, evince

*note* this is probably a duplicate, in fact I'm sure it must be a
 duplicate, but I can't find it anywhere. There are questions about
 font rendering or incorrect fonts in evince, but as far as I can
 tell, not the specific case I am referring to here.

It seems that evince does not handle display fonts well. If I open a PDF in
Acroread (or whatever the PDF reader from Adobe is called nowadays),
it looks fine, but when I open the same PDF in *Evince*, the results
look horrible. Here is a comparison:

[image]

(*Evince* is the **lower sample**)

Does anyone know how to force Evince to display the fonts correctly
or, as an alternative, suggest a better alternative to Evince? Overall
I like Evince because it is fast and secure (it doesn't execute
embedded JavaScript which appears to be the most commonly spread
vulnerabilities from the interwebs lately), but I'm happy to consider alternatives.

Comment: Those look like different fonts. Can you try with a PDF that contains embedded fonts, or install the fonts that are being used in that PDF?

Comment: @muru It happens on _all_ PDFs, so either the fonts _are_ installed (thus accessible by Acroread) or they are embedded already. Besides, it was the _same_ PDF viewed on the same system. The only difference was the reader.

Comment: Yes, but what I am trying to track down is this: does Acrobat have a different set of fonts, or otherwise selects fonts differently. I strongly doubt the PDFs you have tested have embedded fonts. This way, we can pin down if this is a font display problem (a bug) or a selection/availability problem.

Comment: Could you upload a small sample file and post it here by editing your answer? That would help  us tremendously in identifying the issue and/or confirming that we are dealing with a bug.

Answer (score 1):

A few years late, but considering I'm having this issue and this was the initial post to pop up on my searches, I figured why not.

I, and others, have this issue. It's apparently been around for awhile. `evince` doesn't render some of the fonts appropriately.

You can check to see if the fonts are embedded within your pdf document and then fix it with `ghostscript`.

I found an article on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277418/the-pdf-viewer-evince-on-linux-can-not-display-some-math-symbols-correctly) that explains it in pretty good detail. It's enough to work off of. Most of the fonts are most likely in your system already (they were installed on my system).

I also happened to find a [slackware](http://notespool.blogspot.com/2010/08/bad-evince-font-in-slackware.html) tutorial post that went in to similar detail.

Technically, and ultimately, though, its just how evince renders the pdf file. I can load my pdf files using different apps and I've noticed each one renders in a unique way.

The only one I've come across that renders it properly is Adobe's Acrobat Reader. I've tested this on multiple systems and devices using all sorts of pdf apps from OSS to Proprietary.

I still use `evince` regardless and sadly I don't have the time right now to play with the source to figure out why this happens. Maybe I, or some one else, will fix it one day. You never know. It is OSS.